# WooCommerce Storefront site-header padding

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css

Can someone please point me what folder/file location of where this precise bit of padding-top definition comes from other than **style.css**?  I can't seem to find any sass/scss files in any of the storefront folders.  padding-top property value appears to be calculated value IMO.

```
@media (min-width:768px){

    .site-header{
        padding-top:2.617924em;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.site-header for storefront is in minified styles.css

[image: styles.css]

Comment: I am looking for the SASS files that build style.css.   The precision value assigned  to padding-top implies that style.css is being generated from SASS or some other set of files.

Comment: if you installed the theme direct it will not come with the sass files you would need to pull it from git.

this is the file you are looking for 

https://github.com/woocommerce/storefront/blob/master/assets/css/base/_base.scss